# Retrieve Checkout Add-Ons Field Value

Tags: woocommerce, metadata, checkout, custom-fields

I'm using WooCommerce [Checkout Add-Ons](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-checkout-add-ons/) plugin to allow customers to attach an image and a caption to their order but can't seem to access that information in my theme. Right now I have:

```
$order_id       = get_the_ID();
$order          = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$order_items    = $order->get_items();

foreach( $order_items as $order_item ):
  printr( $order_item );
endforeach;
```

The trouble is that it's only returning the first line item, in this case the product name. There's two other line items stored here though:

```
order_item_id   order_item_name         order_item_type     order_id
1               Open Category Entry     line_item           329
2               Image Upload            fee                 329
3               Image Caption           fee                 329
```

(in wp_woocommerce_order_items)

How can I retrieve the rest?

What I need to go on to do is recover the value of _wc_checkout_add_on_value from the wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta table.

Answer (score 0):

Having had a look at the source I found that `$order->get_items()` accepts a `$types` parameter and defaults to `type='line_item'` if none is specified. I added `'fee'` to my call for items and got exactly what I was looking for.

http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_abstract_orderget_items/